# How do I make an Image show up in a Java Swing Applet

Tags: java, image, swing, japplet

How do I make an `Image` show up in a Java Swing Applet?

Comment: Copyedited; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to add it as an Icon to a JLabel that you put on your GUI.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel(javax.swing.Icon)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of what you need

```
class myApplet extends JApplet {
        private BufferedImage image;

        myApplet() {
            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("insert image path here"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // handle exception...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 

        }
    }
```

Comment: -3  1) That is not a Swing applet.  2) A File will not work except in a digitally signed & trusted applet.  3) A File will only work in a trusted applet, if it is at the exact address on the end user's local file system as specified in the image path.  URLs should be used instead, and those URLs should be formed either relative to the document/code base, or discovered using getResource().

Comment: @Andrew I was just trying to guide the OP hence I used the word outline. I wanted to give the OP something to start with. Beside, the OP never mentioned anything about trusted applets.